# how to make sure that hibernate committed a transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, thread-safety

I've got a very weird behavior, in my java (spring) application, I've a case where i save an object using hibernateTemplate, then calling a thread which try to get this object again using hibernateTemplate, if am running in debug mode every thing is working fine, but when am not, it most of time give me null pointer exception, as the object returned back from the second call in the thread returns a null object,

so bottom-line here is: i think hibernate didn't commit its transaction, before the thread is started,

so how to make sure that the object is saved i DB before the thread starts,

Regards,

Comment: How are you specifying your transaction boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing a flush() should do the job.

Comment: i did that, but it didn't help this time, i excuted a flush, and the a refresh, but that didn't help

Comment: Ok, got me then. Thats what I remember doing when we hit something similar on a project years ago. Flush() should flush all the changes. best way to confirm is to turn on sql logging in hibernate and watch the logs. You should see the sql statements execute to insert the records. If thats ok, then I'd be looking at your other thread.

Comment: The problem is that there are _two_ levels of caching / flushing involved here: From the point of view of the application there's first Hibernate that will collect requests internally and only flush them to the database when needed (or explicitly called). But then there's also the transaction handling of the database itself: Even after Hibernate has sent SQL calls to the database, the database might only execute them within a transaction, and changes do not become visible to thread #2 until the transaction from thread #1 is committed.

Answer (score 0):

> so bottom-line here is: I think hibernate didn't commit its transaction, before the thread is started

Why would Hibernate do that? Actually, Hibernate doesn't provide automatic transaction handling.

> so how to make sure that the object is saved i DB before the thread starts,

Commit the transaction started in Thread #1 before starting the new Thread #2.

Without more details about your Spring/Hibernate setup and the transaction handling, it will be hard to get a more detailed answer IMO.

Comment: could you please tell me what exactly configurations you want to know, i really appreciate your help